# FileUpload does not work with Razor Webpages 2

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-webpages, razor-2

I have tried to install MVC3, MVC4 and Webpages 2 on the IIS and it keeps telling me that `@FileUpload.GetHTML` does not exist...

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service >this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'FileUpload' does not exist in the current context
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 17:     <body>
Line 18:     <h1>FileUpload - Single-File Example</h1>
Line 19:     @FileUpload.GetHtml(                     <---- RED LINE
Line 20:         initialNumberOfFiles:1,
Line 21:         allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
```

I've tried to copy the dll's manually to make sure they are the correct version etc.

- System.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deloyment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

The examples from Microsoft seems to include Microsoft.Web.Helpers ??? Cant find that anywhere in Razor (v2)...

is FileUpload not part of Helpers in Razor V2?

Answer (score 5):

`@FileUpload.GetHTML` is not part of the `System.Web.Helpers` assembly. It's part of the [`Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Helpers.Mvc`](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Helpers.Mvc/) NuGet that you must install in your project:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Helpers.Mvc
```

Comment: I just realise that you didnt answer correctly. This helper is called "Microsoft.Web.Helpers.dll" no MVC in that.

Comment: But I appricate the effort though eventhough I found the answer before your post. So thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

FOUND IT! Finally! NuGet package missing.

The Microsoft.Web.Helpers isn't part of neither MVC3, MVC4, Razor v2, WebMatrix 2.

You just need to add the NuGet packaged called: "ASP.NET Web Helpers Library" (why its called ASP.NET and not Microsoft is a little stupid to me, but thats the one you need to get the FileUpload.GetHTML helper to assitance.

I didnt pay attention to it, as it states in NuGet that:

> This package contains web helpers to easily add functionality to your site such as Captcha validation, Twitter profile and search boxes, Gravatars, Video, Bing search, site analytics or themes.

So, figuring out that UPLOAD also was part of this, wasn't really clear to me.

Thought I would share this with fellow confusers :-)